# How to close iframe window on reload page with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

I have website in PHP.And my situation is that I have checkout page that I need to click on submit button for payment process in iframe window. After complete payment process, I need to close iframe window and redirect to success page.But iframe did not close and page redirected into iframe.

Code look like this:

```
<form><input type="button" name="payfort" value="Continue" onclick="CreditPay();" id="payfort" class="payfort" /></form>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function CreditPay() {                

                    var pop = document.getElementById('popup-win');
                    pop.style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('overlay').className = 'show';
                    document.getElementById('payfortForm').submit();
                    return false;
           }</script>
```

And below code is open in iframe:

```
<div class="popup-win" id="popup-win" style="display: none;">
    <div class="popup-header">
    </div>
    <div class="popup-subtitle">
        Transaction Value:<span class='currency-txt'>AED&nbsp; 17.00</span>
    </div>
    <iframe id="ifrmPAYFORT" name="ifrmPAYFORT" style="width: 100%; height: 450px"></iframe></div>

<div class="overlay" id="overlay"></div>
    <form METHOD="post" ACTION="http://localhost/phppayfort/success.php" id="payfortForm" name="payfortForm" target="ifrmPAYFORT">

        <input type="hidden" name="service_command" value="<?php echo $requestParams['service_command'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="language" value="<?php echo $requestParams['language'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="merchant_identifier" value="<?php echo $requestParams['merchant_identifier'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="access_code" value="<?php echo $requestParams['access_code'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<?php echo $signature ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php echo $requestParams['return_url'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="merchant_reference" value="<?php echo $requestParams['merchant_reference'] ?>">
    </form>
```

So, is there any way to close iframe window on reload page?

Many thanks in advance for recommendations.

Comment: Please show some code?

Comment: By `close iframe window`, you mean you want to remove specific iFrame element from DOM?

Comment: If you have the php code inside your iframe, it isn't possible to redirect outside the iframe. You can try to open the redirect-page in a new tab instead and close the other tab

Comment: Not enough information. How did you insert that `iframe`? What did you mean "*But iframe did not close and page redirected into iframe*"? Show us some of the code regarding my questions.

Comment: That's... not... code...  that is a random piece of HTML-markup.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  I  added complete code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a class for your iframe, like:

```
<iframe class="myiframe"></iframe>
```

And play with some JS, when form submited, update class="myiframe" and add 'display: none;'.

For redirection, you can use href.location

How to hide your iframe:

```
iframeToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("myiframe");
iframeToHide.style.display = "none";
```

How to redirect:

```
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
```

Note, this is a JS solution, with PHP I don't know if you will be able to solve this.

Cheers!